# User function not defined within a class and Unit Testing

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, oop, initialization

I am trying to create a class which can standardize a pandas dataframe. I have created a fit method within the class to get the mean and standard deviation. My aim is to call the fit method in the transform method (defined within the class). However it shows as not defined

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statistics as st

class standardize:

    def fit(self):
        mean = sum(self)/len(self)
        std_dev = round(st.stdev(self),2)
        return mean,std_dev

    def transform(self):
        data_fitted = self.fit()
        data_transformed = []
        for i in self:
            self[i] = (self[i] - data_fitted.mean)/(data_fitted.std_dev)
            data_transformed = data_transformed.append()
        return data_transformed

    def inverse_transform(self):
        data_transformed = self.transform()
        inverse_transformed = []
        for i in data_transformed:
            self.data_transformed[i] = 
            (self.data_transformed[i]*data_fitted.stddev)+(data_fitted.mean)
            inverse_transformed = inverse_transformed.append()
        return inverse_transformed  


stock_data = {'Day': ['Day_1','Day_2','Day_3','Day_4','Day_5','Day_6','Day_7'],
              'Daily_Closing_Price': [7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}
series_1 = pd.DataFrame(stock_data, columns = ['Day','Daily_Closing_Price'])
x = standardize.fit(series_1['Daily_Closing_Price'])
print(x)
y = standardize.transform(series_1['Daily_Closing_Price'])
print(y)
z = standardize.inverse_transform(series_1['Daily_Closing_Price'])
print(z)
```

I get the initial output of print(x) with mean and standard deviation value. However after that I get the following error.

```
(10.0, 2.16)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-0ee877b48308> in <module>
        4 x = standardize.fit(series_1['Daily_Closing_Price'])
        5 print(x)
  ----> 6 y = standardize.transform(series_1['Daily_Closing_Price'])
        7 z = standardize.inverse_transform(series_1['Daily_Closing_Price'])
        8 print(y)

<ipython-input-87-71f5759b9dac> in transform(self)
        7 
        8     def transform(self):
        ----> 9         data_fitted = self.fit()
        10         data_transformed = []
        11         for i in self:

        ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
        5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
        5178                 return self[name]
        -> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        5180 
        5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

        AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

I have 3 main questions here.

1. Is it compulsory or prudent to write an `__init__` method for this use case. If yes, then how would that fit in?
2. How to use the fit method for transform method (and subsequently transform for `inverse_transform`)?
3. How do I write a unit test class to make sure the class correctly standardizes a column of data, and then another unit test to make sure it correctly inverse transforms a column of standardized data.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the post. We can't see which functions are actually part of the class or not.

Comment: @mkrieger1..apologies for the inconvenience. I have made the recommended edits. Hope it is now legible.